# How to find a base of the "opposite" vector subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

First of all, I'm not a native speaker so it's hard for me to use the formal English math language. So to explain my question first: by subspace X opposite to subspace Y I mean such subspace, that the sum of X and Y gives the full vector space.

The example I'm working on is this:
$$ X=\{p \in \Bbb{C}[x]_5: p(0)=p(1)=p(-1) \} $$

Now, I've found it's base  ($x^5-x^3,x^2-x^4,x-x^3,1$), but I'm stuck with the next problem: find a base of the vector subspace Y such that $X \oplus Y=\Bbb{C}[x]_5$. I understand that Y contains all the elements of $\Bbb{C}[x]_5$ that are not included in X. How can I find the base of Y (and prove that it indeed contains all the elements not included in X), aside from trials and errors? Is there a general rule of thumb for problems like this one?

**Edit**: *I was wrong about Y in my example, but I'm still curious about the general problem of looking for bases of opposite subspaces.*

Thanks!

Comment: $Y$ does *not* contain all the elements of $\mathbb{C}[x]_5$ that are not included in $X$. It only contains some of them. Which ones exactly depends on the choice of $Y$ (which is not unique).

Comment: How's so? If Y contains only some elements, $X \oplus Y$ would not be equal to $\Bbb{C}[x]_5$ since some elements would be omitted in the sum. What do I do wrong?

Comment: $X \oplus Y$ is a direct sum, which is larger than the simple set-theoretic union $X \cup Y$. To say that $\mathbb{C}[x]_5 = X \oplus Y$ is the same as to say that $X \cap Y = \{0\}$ and each vector $v \in \mathbb{C}[x]_5$ can be represented as a sum $v = x + y$, where $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$.

Comment: For example, look at the space $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $X = \{(a, 0) \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $Y = \{(0, b) \mid b \in \mathbb{R}\}$, then $X \oplus Y = \mathbb{R}^2$, but there are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that do not belong to either $X$ or $Y$, for instance $v = (1, 1)$.

Comment: But $Y$ in my example above is also not unique. For instance if you look at another subspace $Y' = \{(c, c) \mid c \in \mathbb{R}\}$, then also $\mathbb{R}^2 = X \oplus Y'$. So there are many ways to choose a subspace $Y$ such that $\mathbb{R}^2 = X \oplus Y$. The same is true in your problem.

Comment: @DanShved Ah, I see! Can you post your comments together in an answer? I don't like leaving unanswered questions behind :)

Comment: My comments don't really answer your question (how to find the base for $Y$). And I don't feel like posting an incomplete answer like that.

Comment: Yeah but I can take it from there, and it's a homework question, so hints are preferred over full solutions, anyway. I'm still curious about looking for bases of opposite subspaces, though, so I guess I'll leave the question open.

Comment: There should be a result in your textbook that says: any linearly independent set of vectors in a vector space $V$ can be extended to a basis for $V$. That result might even have a constructive version. That's what you're trying to do here: extend the linearly independent set $\{x^5-x^4-x^3,x^2,x-2x^4,1\}$ into a basis for $\mathbb C[x]_5$; then the newly added vectors will be a basis for $Y$. (And there are many possible correct answers.)

Comment: Another possibility is to introduce an inner product and use Gram-Schmidt on the linearly dependent set $\{x^5-x^4-x^3,x^2,x-2x^4,1,1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}$; that is one way to produce a basis for the whole vector space whose first part is a basis for the given subspace.

Comment: Ahh the first idea is brilliant in its simplicity and transparency! It all looks so easy now. And yes, I know that result. I had all the dots I needed in front of me, but I just couldn't connect them. Can someone please post an answer :D

Comment: P.S: I found a silly miscalculation in my base, see the edited OP.